# Speech recognition returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with getting Speech Recognition to work.
Its probably some stupid mistake. It constantly returns undefined.
I've been looking through post here on stackoverflow and staring at the code for hours..
Can anyone please help me spot my error?

```
<script>
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
var SpeechRecognitionEvent = SpeechRecognitionEvent || webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent
var ordnummer = 0;
var saetning = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
var saetning_laengde = saetning.split(" ").length;
console.log(saetning);
console.log(saetning_laengde);

var ord = [ 'Jeg' , 'hedder' , 'Ib'];
var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar ord; public <ord> = ' + ord.join(' | ') + ' ;'  
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.lang = 'da-DK';
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

var diagnostic = document.querySelector('.output');
var bg = document.querySelector('html');
var hints = document.querySelector('.hints');

hints.innerHTML = 'Tap/click og læs derefter sætningen.';

document.body.onclick = function() {
  recognition.start();
  console.log('Parat');
}

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  var last = event.results.length - 1;
  var sagt = event.results[0].transcript;
  diagnostic.textContent = 'Result received: ' + event.results[0].transcript + '.';
  console.log(event.results[0].transcript);
  console.log('Confidence: ' + event.results[0][0].confidence);
  if(saetning==sagt){
    ordnummer= ordnummmer + 1;
    console.log('Korrekt');
  } else { console.log('Forkert'); }
}

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
  recognition.stop();
}

recognition.onnomatch = function(event) {
  diagnostic.textContent = "Det forstod jeg ikke.. Prøv igen!";
}

recognition.onerror = function(event) {
  diagnostic.textContent = 'Error occurred in recognition: ' + event.error;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please be more specific as it is not clear what you mean by "returns undefined". *What* exactly returns `undefined`?

Comment: Checked your code and could not find any error. Please be more specific.